# Create google chart in column of html Table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Html Table and i Have Filled the data dynamically through javascript in the table I want google image chart in one of the columns of table but m not getting the chart for all the rows and it is not accepting value more than 1000, I have used this url to create the graph 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:" + parameters+ "&chs=50x30' parameters are the values passed to create the google imagechart.
Please help me to know where the problem is and how to solve it.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the google chart API on a project currently and it's been great.  Your invocation should work, just make sure that *parameters* contains only a comma separated list of number values without spaces.

E.g. parameters = 5,19,7

Your full string is https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:5,19,7&chs=500x300.

I made the image a bit larger than your 50x30 so you could see what was happening.  I think it's going to be hard to make an effective graph of any kind at the scale you're working with, even with the options google gives you to change the graph appearance.  It will be especially hard to produce a useful line graph.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I was getting space so the graph could not be created ,I have solved that with .trim() function and I m getting result.